# Tener dos TabBarControllers en una App en iOS

Tags: xcode, swift4

Quisiera saber cómo podría hacer para tener dos interfaces diferentes en mi APP mi idea es la siguiente, al iniciar mi sesión como Admin que me muestre una interface y cuando ingrese como cliente otra interfaces, estuve pensando en crear dos archivos .storyboard y usar los storyboard reference para así ligar los dos archivos. Pero aún no sé si se puede. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo afondaría de la siguiente manera, solo para darte una idea:

Yo pondría un viewController para inicio de sesión y luego usaría un segue con su propiedad identifier o un present para según el usuario y contraseña introducido te dirija a al tabBar1 o al tabBar2.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Es lo mismo que pensé, te agradezco tu respuesta un abrazo!